# Populate an input when checkbox is checked from ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-checked

I'm trying to populate an input two ways. The first method is to simply type an amount into the input, which works perfectly. The second method (which I'm struggling with) is to check the checkbox generated within the ngRepeat directive.

The desired behavior is that the checkbox will take the value of item.amount from the JSON data and populate the input with that value. Here is the markup:

```
<table class="table table-striped header-fixed" id="invoiceTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="first-cell">Select</th>
        <th class="inv-res2">Invoice #</th>
        <th class="inv-res3">Bill Date</th>
        <th class="inv-res4">Amount</th>
        <th class="inv-res5">Amount to Pay</th>
        <th class="inv-res6"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-if="invoices.length" ng-repeat="item in invoices | filter: {status:'Unpaid'}">
        <td class="first-cell"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td class="inv-res2"><a href="invoices/{{item.invoiceNum}}">{{item.invoiceNum}}</a></td>
        <td class="inv-res3">{{item.creationDate}}</td>
        <td class="inv-res4" ng-init="invoices.total.amount = invoices.total.amount + item.amount">{{item.amount | currency}}</td>
        <td class="inv-res5">$
          <input ng-validate="number" type="number" class="input-mini" ng-model="item.payment" ng-change="getTotal()" step="0.01"  /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="totals-row" >
        <td colspan="3" class="totals-cell"><h4>Account Balance:&nbsp;<span class="status-error">{{invoices.total.amount | currency }}</span></h4></td>
        <td class="inv-res4"><h5>Total to pay:</h5></td>
        <td class="inv-res5">{{total | currency}}</td>
        <td class="inv-res6"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
    myApp.controller('invoiceList', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('assets/js/lib/angular/invoices.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.invoices = data;
    });

    $scope.sum = function(list) {
         var total=0;
         angular.forEach(list , function(item){
            total+= parseInt(item.amount);
         });
         return total;
    };



    $scope.total = 0;
    $scope.getTotal = function() {
        $scope.total = 0;
        $scope.invoices.forEach(function(item){
            $scope.total += parseFloat(item.payment);
        });
    };

    $scope.pushPayment = function(item){
        if($scope.checked == 'checked'){
          return item.payment;
        }
    };  

}]);
```

Comment: is the `checked` property not a boolean? If so if you are setting this to the `ng-model` it will return true or false. There is also no `checked` property on the `$scope` this is no problem because this will be added automatically to the $scope but then it is always false. I think you want to have `item.checked` or something like that.

Comment: What does your `invoices` data structure look like?

Comment: Good Question:    [
  {
    "invoiceNum": "312490",
    "amount": 14.20,
    "creationDate": "2015-03-07",
    "status": "Paid",
 "payment": 0
  },     ...

Comment: What would the truthy and falsy values for the checkbox represent for a data point like `amount`

Comment: Not sure I established any. Essentially, I'm looking for the angular equivalent of "foreach, if checkbox is:checked, then input value=item.amount"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the assistance, but I think I was overthinking it. I got to work with simply adding:

```
ng-click="item.payment=item.amount" ng-change="getTotal()"
```

to the checkbox. I still have to incorporate this into the sum function, but I solved the issue.

Comment: Whilst this will work when checking the checkbox, it will also populate your input when you uncheck... Is that the behavior you want?

Comment: I actually do desire the functionality you're describing and thought that would be the case when I applied it. However, I've discovered that what actually happens is that the value doesn't even change until the second click, and no amount of clicks on the checkbox will remove the amount.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want a toggle-able check box, If it is checked then you want to copy that invoices amount into the input box below. You could do something similar to below with a combination of `ng-model` and `ng-change`

```
<tr ng-if="invoices.length" ng-repeat="item in invoices | filter: {status:'Unpaid'}">
    <td class="first-cell">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" ng-change="select(item)"/>
    </td>
    <td class="inv-res5">$
      <input ng-validate="number" type="number" class="input-mini" ng-model="item.payment" step="0.01"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and add the following to your controller

```
$scope.select = function(item) {
    if(item.checked){
       item.payment = item.amount;
    }
}
```

What this should do:

- You bind the status of the check box to `$scope.checked` using `ng-model`
- Every time the checkbox status changes `ng-change` is called, therefore `selectInvoice` is called.
- Select invoice checks whether the checkbox is checked and adjusts the `item.payment` value accordingly which is bound to the `inputs` `ng-model`

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xEQvRMU8Pf9vCbX46y7A?p=preview) for a working example (Note I thinned out the code so its only the bit we're interested in

---

As an aside, you don't need to have the input box call `getTotal` when its value changes. Just change the last few lines to:

```
<td class="inv-res4"><h5>Total to pay:</h5></td>
<td class="inv-res5">{{getTotal() | currency}}</td>
```

And modify your JavaScript to:

```
$scope.getTotal = function() {
    var total = 0;
    $scope.invoices.forEach(function(item){
        total += parseFloat(item.payment);
    });
    return total;
};
```

It will still be up to date every time Angular 'digests'

Comment: This looks a lot better than what I was trying to do, however, I'm getting an Unexpected Token error and my editor is telling me that item is undefined (on $scope.selectInvoice(item) { and on item.payment = item.amount; line).

Comment: @ChristianHill Sorry there was an error in my JavaScript, I've fixed it above

Comment: This seems like it should work, but it isn't. Just to verify, you are proposing that I should replace my scope.pushPayment function with yours, correct?

Comment: @ChristianHill Technically you shouldnt need the pushPayment method any more

Comment: OK thanks. I replaced it but it still didnt work. I did manage to solve it below. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: @ChristianHill I've added a Plunker and made some more code fixes

Answer (score 0):

**[The Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wDKi3RjeR58UrZilLhRr?p=preview)**

**The html:**

```
<table class="table table-striped header-fixed" id="invoiceTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="first-cell">Select</th>
        <th class="inv-res2">Invoice #</th>
        <th class="inv-res3">Bill Date</th>
        <th class="inv-res4">Amount</th>
        <th class="inv-res5">Amount to Pay</th>
        <th class="inv-res6"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in mainCtrl.invoiceList.invoices">
        <td class="first-cell"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" /></td>
        <td class="inv-res2"><a href="invoices/{{item.invoiceNum}}">{{item.invoiceNum}}</a></td>
        <td class="inv-res3">{{item.creationDate}}</td>
        <td class="inv-res4" ng-init="invoices.total.amount = invoices.total.amount + item.amount">{{item.amount | currency}}</td>
        <td class="inv-res5">$
          <input type="text" ng-model="mainCtrl.getAmount(item)"/></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="totals-row" >
        <td colspan="3" class="totals-cell"><h4>Account Balance:&nbsp;<span class="status-error">{{invoices.total.amount | currency }}</span></h4></td>
        <td class="inv-res4"><h5>Total to pay:</h5></td>
        <td class="inv-res5">{{mainCtrl.getTotalAmount()}}</td>
        <td class="inv-res6"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**The JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['tempDataStorageService', function(tempDataStorageService) {

  var myCtrl = this;

    myCtrl.invoiceList = tempDataStorageService;

    myCtrl.getAmount = function(item){
      return item.selected? item.amount : "";
    };

    myCtrl.getTotalAmount = function(){
      var total = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < tempDataStorageService.invoices.length; i++){
        if(tempDataStorageService.invoices[i].selected){
          total = total + tempDataStorageService.invoices[i].amount;
        }
      }
      return total;
    }

}]);


app.factory('tempDataStorageService', function() {
    // The service object
    var storage = this;


    storage.invoices = [{invoiceNum: 1, creationDate: "1/1/16", amount: 1.50, selected: false}, 
                        {invoiceNum: 2, creationDate: "1/2/16", amount: 2.50, selected: false},
                        {invoiceNum: 2, creationDate: "1/2/16", amount: 2.50, selected: false},
                        {invoiceNum: 3, creationDate: "1/3/16", amount: 3.50, selected: false},
                        {invoiceNum: 4, creationDate: "1/4/16", amount: 4.50, selected: false},
                        {invoiceNum: 5, creationDate: "1/5/16", amount: 5.50, selected: false},
                        {invoiceNum: 6, creationDate: "1/6/16", amount: 6.50, selected: false},
                        {invoiceNum: 7, creationDate: "1/7/16", amount: 7.50, selected: false},
                        {invoiceNum: 8, creationDate: "1/8/16", amount: 8.50, selected: false}];

    // return the service object
    return storage;
});
```

That's a way of doing it

Comment: Your input ng-model is bound to a `function` which means you cant edit the input field currently

Comment: Thanks but you've replaced the ngModel on my input which disables the other functionality.

Comment: Fair enough. I set the binding to the amount. [The plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iN8ln0e8bRpB7QkM5v1K?p=preview) I still don't know if this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks though! If I didn't need to support manual input of the inputs your answer would've been spot on.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute `amountToPay` to your invoices and send the item to the `getTotal` function:

```
<input ng-validate="number" type="number" class="input-mini" value="{{pushPayment()}}" 
    ng-model="item.amountToPay" ng-change="getTotal(item)" step="0.01"  /></td>
```

In your checkbox change the ng-model to item.checked:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.checked" /></td>
```

Add this to your `getTotal()` function:

```
   $scope.getTotal = function(item) {
            item.checked = true; 
            $scope.total = 0;
            $scope.invoices.forEach(function(item){
                $scope.total += parseFloat(item.payment);
            });
        };
```

If you need to populate your input, just modify the `amountToPay` attribute